# Using a loop to string together a list of variables with filenames

Tags: string, bash, shell, loops, unix

I have created a script that identifies a unique set of files (from a large list) and saves the file paths as unique variables (e.g. $vol1, $vol2, $vol3... see below).

```
for volume in `seq 1 $num_ap_files` 
    do
    bindex=$(cat ../b0_volumes_tmp.txt | head -$volume | tail -1)
    eval 'vol'${volume}=$(cat ../all_volumes.txt | head -$bindex | tail -1)
    done
```

I'd like to concatenate the variables into one string variable to use as input for a separate command line program. As the number of volumes may differ - it seems most appropriate to create a loop of the following nature (??? define where I am having trouble):

```
??? files=$vol1
for i in `seq 2 $num_ap_files
do
??? eval files=${files}" $vol"${i) 
done
```

I've tried a few different options here using files+=, eval function, etc. and continue to get an error message: -bash: vol0001.nii.gz: command not found. Is there a way around this? The filenames need to be in string format to be fed into subsequent processing steps.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Have you considered using an array instead? You don't have to mess around with numbered variables and you can easily pass them all at once to a command

Comment: Hmmm, when I do that... files=(); a=1; while [ "$a" -le "$subNum" ]; do eval files+=('$vol'${volume}); ((a++)); done... I get the following error. bash: [: : integer expression expected. I imaginge, I'm doing something wrong. Still learning.

Comment: Please add a sample `b0_volumes_tmp.txt` and `all_volumes.txt` file to your question so we can try your code and suggest improvements.

Comment: https://rochester.box.com/s/cgzym6vq03z3ysgt348tasiv0n1zlnm2

Comment: https://rochester.box.com/s/55lr4d1b4chodvzkifbgc2ws53097mlk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array for this:

```
vol=()
for ((volume = 1; volume <= num_ap_files; volume++)); do
    bindex=$(sed -n "$volume p" ../b0_volumes_tmp.txt)
    vol[$volume]=$(sed -n "$bindex p" ../all_volumes.txt)
done

files="${vol[*]}"
```

The variable `files` contains the content of the array `vol` as one single string.

If you now want to call a command with each element of `vol` as an argument, no need to use an intermediate variable like `files`:

```
my_next_command "${vol[@]}"
```

Note: the command `sed -n "$N p" file` prints the Nth line of the file (the same as your `cat file | head -$N | tail -1`)

Comment: Works! Appreciate your help.

Comment: files="${vol[*]}" seems to be the key here. Not sure why that was so difficult for me.

Comment: @DavidPaul In my opinion, the key is using arrays in the first place. Avoid `eval` like the plague.